# Deployed Webpack - Bootstrap Not Working - DigitalOcean

Tags: express, nginx, webpack, digital-ocean, bootstrap-4

I'm **deploying** my **first** webpack app. I probably have a few **misconceptions**. 

My (simple) app is **Webpack2** + **Bootstrap4** + **ReactJS**. 

I ran ... `npm run prod` (the **optimizing** sequence). 

My "**dist**" folder now contains the **files** & **folder** that I list **below**. 

I use **DigitalOcean**, **Nginx**, **express**, ... to deploy my **Webpack** app. 

I uploaded my **Webpack** app into a **directory** that is in my DigitalOcean **top** directory. 

In this directory named "**wp2-bs4-rjs**", I placed: 

**index.html**, **app.bundle.js**, **app.css**, **imgs** (folder). 

This "**wp2-bs4-rjs**" directory also contains: 

**package.json** (for **express**) & **node_modules** folder (for **express**, for **deployment**). 

I'm **assuming** my Webpack app does **not** use the **node_modules** folder, 

**now** that it has been **optimized** (?). 

**IMPORTANT**: When I use **webpack-dev-server** in my **computer**'s localhost, 

the **Bootstrap** & **jQuery** works (everything works).

**BUT**, when I view my Webpack app **online**, I see the **text** and its background **image**, 

but **no** Bootstrap influence. 

Since I **see** my background **image** & my **css** styles, I **know** the **app.css** file is properly **working**. 

**Also**, since I see my **text**, I know my **app.bundle.js** file is **partially** working. 

**BUT**, for **some** reason, the **Bootstrap** & **jQuery** in my **app.bundle.js** file is **not** working. 

I have **no** errors in my JavaScript **console** & the **networking** tab. 

Do you have any **ideas** of what I'm doing **wrong** ? 

Here's it's **URL**: [wp2-bs4-rjs](http://m-rooney.com/wp2-bs4-rjs/) 

My **Webpack** app is **served** on my **domain**'s localhost, port 3000, using **reverse proxy**. 

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Thank-you, MLR 

======================================================================== 

**Update**: I tried installing a few Node packages as **dependencies**, 

to see if it made a difference. It did **not**. 

Installed in my **DigitalOcean** server & my **computer**'s webpack-dev-server (Webpack project): 

"babel-cli": "^6.24.1", "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1", "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1", "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6", "express": "^4.15.3", "jquery": "^3.2.1", "react": "^15.6.1", "react-dom": "^15.6.1", "tether": "^1.4.0", "webpack": "^3.0.0" 

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

**Not** installed in my **DigitalOcean** server >Webpack project, 

**but** is installed in my **computer**'s webpack-dev-server version: 

ejs, css-loader, style-loader, sass-loader, node-sass, extract-text-webpack-plugin, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader, babel-core, rimraf, file-loader, image-webpack-loader, libpng, bootstrap-loader, resolve-url-loader, url-loader, imports-loader exports-loader, postcss  postcss-loader, purifycss-webpack, purify-css 

======================================================================== 

**Update**: Since the **node_modules** folder is in the **same** directory as **app.bundle.js** ... 

& **all** the other (non-image) **files**, ... 

in the **app.bundle.js**, I tried changing **all** occurrences of `./node_modules` to `node_modules`. 

It did **not** work. Although my problem could be a **combination** of **errors**. 

======================================================================== 

Hi olore, here's my Webpack **config** (as you asked).

```
'use strict';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const PurifyCSSPlugin = require('purifycss-webpack');

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const cssDev = ['style-loader','css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader'];
const cssProd = ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: ['css-loader','sass-loader'],
    publicPath: '/dist'
});
let cssConfig = isProd ? cssProd : cssDev;

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js','.jsx','.html','.css','.scss'] },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: cssConfig// potentially the ExtractTextPlugin.extract(...)
            },{
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },{
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=imgs/&publicPath=./',
                    'image-webpack-loader'
                ]
            },{
                test: /\.(woff2?|svg)$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },{
                test: /\.(ttf|eot)$/,
                use: 'file-loader&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },{
                test: /bootstrap[\/\\]dist[\/\\]js[\/\\]umd[\/\\]/,
                use: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery'
            }
        ],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        open: true,
        stats: 'errors-only'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'ReactJS Webpack Bootstrap',
            hash: true,
            template: './index.html',
            minify: {collapseWhitespace: true}
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            disable: !isProd,
            allChunks: true
        }),
        new PurifyCSSPlugin({
            paths: glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')),
            purifyOptions: { minify: true }
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            Tether: "tether",
            "window.Tether": "tether",
            Alert: "exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
            Button: "exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button",
            Carousel: "exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
            Collapse: "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
            Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
            Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
            Popover: "exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
            Scrollspy: "exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
            Tab: "exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
            Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
            Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util"
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Please post your webpack config

Comment: Thank-you olore. I also added an **update**; failed experiment results that may be helpful. It concerns the placement of my **node_modules** folder in relation to the **app.bundle.js** file. ... The **spell checker** keeps removing the first "o" from your name.

Comment: you shouldn't need to install all your dev dependencies onto the server. The bundle should contain everything you need. I can see jQuery and Bootstrap in your bundle. I've never used ProvidePlugin, but have dealt with jQuery in webpack with 

{
  test: require.resolve('jquery'),
  use: [
   'expose-loader?jQuery',
   'expose-loader?$'
  ]
},

More detail: https://brian.olore.net/wp/2017/06/journey-to-webpack-part-3-finish-the-vendors/

Comment: olore, I glean from your reply, you see no crippling errors. Thanks for confirming, "my Webpack project (**dist** folder content) no longer needs it's **node_modules** folder. ... Also, it does not need its **package.json** file, ... I am only referring to what my **Webpack project** needs. Not what my **server** needs. - - As I mentioned in my **original** question, "When I use **webpack-dev-server** in my computer's **localhost**, everything works.". - - I will experiment with your provided linked material. Thnx

Comment: olore (Please see my **above** comment. Then read the **following**), I uploaded my **full** project into my **DigitalOcean** project folder, then, I ran the **production** (optimization) sequence. I kept fixing its sequential errors. It did **not** work. At least I (also) know the **identical** folder/file structure (compared to my **computer** version) renders the **same** results as I **originally** described (only **Bootstrap4** & **jQuery** does **not** work). Thnx